# Plot a community matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

How can I plot a simple 2x2 community matrix in R? The colours should change for 0, <0 or >0 values of the matrix entries.

This is a sample of what I want to get at the end:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 2):

`sign` will give `-1`, `0`, or `1` depending on whether the input value is `<0`, `0`, or `>0`.

```
sign(c(10.5, -6, 0, 0.1, 3))
#[1]  1 -1  0  1  1
```

Then, it's a matter of preparing the data (`d` in example below) for using the `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)

#Data
m = matrix(c(-1, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 2)
m
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   -1    0
#[2,]    0    1

#Convert to long format
d = data.frame(row = factor(c(row(m))),
               column = factor(c(col(m))),
               value = factor(c(sign(m))))
d
#  row column value
#1   1      1    -1
#2   2      1     0
#3   1      2     0
#4   2      2     1


ggplot(d, aes(x = row, y = column, fill = value)) + geom_tile()
```

[image]

If your matrix `m` has row names and column names, use:

```
d = data.frame(row = factor(row.names(m)[c(row(m))]),
               column = factor(colnames(m)[c(col(m))]),
               value = factor(c(sign(m))))
```

Comment: That looks quite good. How can I choose red for <0, white/empty for 0 and green for >0?

Comment: @witizer, add `+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "white", "green"))` after `geom_tile()`